# Accessing cached ApplicationContext in spring

Tags: java, spring

I need to fetch a singleton bean from same ApplicationContext twice in 2 different classes.

Example snippet :

```
CLass A {
  public void foo(){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("common.spring.xml");
    MyParametrizedSingletonClass myParametrizedSingletonClass = (MyParametrizedSingletonClass) context.getBean("myParametrizedSingletonClass");
    // do more stuff..
  }
CLass B {
  public void bar(){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("common.spring.xml");
    MyParametrizedSingletonClass myParametrizedSingletonClass = (MyParametrizedSingletonClass) context.getBean("myParametrizedSingletonClass");
    // do more stuff..
  }
```

Since MyParametrizedSingletonClass is a singletom it if its constructor is called more than once for same constructor arguments it throws error.

How do I cache and reuse ApplicationContext with spring?

Comment: Why are you constructing the application context yourself, why aren't you injecting the dependency into Classes `A` and `B`? IMHO those should be spring managed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two different context, so even if bean is singleton it will create single instance per context,

if you want to cache application context [you can create a class and provide singleton instance of application context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java/71399#71399)

Answer (score 0):

`Autowire` the bean.

By default the spring injects the autowired beans into required classes and these beans are not created an new everytime. They are singleton by default.

Answer (score 0):

in common.spring.xml file for the bean name myParametrizedSingletonClass add the scope singleton to it as a parameter while defining the bean in the xml file